# Doing automated jobs using curl in php

Tags: php, curl, jobs

I have been looking to do automated jobs on an external site. I have been told that I should be using curl, so I guess I am asking if curl is an option? And how would I go about doing that with these input fields:

```
name="fname"
name="lname"
name="bio"
name="website"
name="email"
name="password"
name="Cpassword"
name="token"
name="submit"
```

Comment: `automated job` is done through `cron`. not using `curl`

Comment: Actually, your question is not _php specific_. To pass variables through http you should use [`query string`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have been told correctly using curl set on a cron job example.

```
//The data
$data = array(
    "fname" => "Mark",
    "lname" => "Jones",
    "Bio" => "Hi i like rose's because they smell nice",
    "website" => "http://mysite.com",
    "email" => "mark@mysite.com",
    "password" => "mypassword",
    "token" => "your token",
    "Agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5"
);

//External site direct link
$external_site = "http://external-site.com";

//Input field names with data ready
$input_fields = "fname=".$data['fname']."&lname=".$data['lname']."&Bio=".$data['bio']."&website=".$data['website']."&email=".$data['email']."&password=".$data['password']."&Cpassword=".$data['password']."&token=".$data['token']."&submit=";

//Do the curl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , $external_site);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $data['Agent']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $input_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$done = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

For more info on curl visit http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php and for cron job's most host's provide a ready cron feature to use XD.